# Using "R CMD pgfSweave" on Mac results in Rcmd error

Tags: r, sweave

I'm having problems running pgfSweave from the command line. In the pgfSweave manual it states that the package must be installed from source in order to be run as:

```
R CMD pgfSweave myfile.Rnw
```

So I installed using:

```
install.packages("pgfSweave", type = "source")
```

and the package appeared to install without a hitch. I then tried running the above R CMD (directly from a bash shell and also from within a make file) and received the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd: line 61: exec: pgfSweave: not found
```

I've read the manuals but haven't come across anyone mentioning this problem. I'm running R version 2.14.0, OSX 10.5.8, and pgfSweave version 1.2.1

(Btw, I should note that I can use the following command from within R with no problem:

```
pgfSweave(file = "myfile.Rnw", compile.tex = FALSE)
```

but i'd like to use a make file and do everything from the command line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pgfSweave` manual provides some nice direction about how you can get the command-line  interface up and running. Here's the key bit, from page 13 of the manual ([warning: pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pgfSweave/vignettes/pgfSweave.pdf)):

> In versions 0.7.0, pgfSweave got an R CMD command line interface. On Unix alikes (including Mac OS X)
>   a symbolic link $R HOME/bin/pgfsweave to $R HOME/library/pgfSweave/exec/pgfsweave-script.R.
>   On Windows a copy of the script is made instead. This script is only installed if pgfSweave is installed
>   from source.

So, for the Mac OS, you just need to place a symbolic link named `pgfsweave` in `$R_HOME/bin/`, pointing to `$R_HOME/library/pgfSweave/exec/pgfsweave-script.R`. (`$R_HOME` is the directory path got by typing `R.home()` at the R command line.)

---

In case you want more details about how this is supposed to be implemented at the time of package installation, have a look at the script `install-script.R` in `$R_HOME/library/pgfSweave/exec/`. It includes separate branches, to be executed depending on the type of operating system, and concludes with this reassuring message (to be printed if installation of the symbolic link fails):

```
cat('\n***********************\n')
cat('Failed to install custom pgfsweave script:\n')
cat('  Thats ok! You can manually install it later.\n')
cat('***********************\n\n')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up - I got it to work creating the symbolic link manually. I didn't, however, get the above "failed to install" message - even though I reinstalled the package from source 3 separate times... strange.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. I thought you'd have mentioned the error message, and am (mildly!) curious about why you didn't get it.

Comment: On further reflection, I'd bet that if you tried to install the package from the command line, using `R CMD INSTALL ...`, you'd see the message. The `install.packages()` call you used constructs and wraps us a call to `R CMD INSTALL`, and likely declines to pass on all of the messages it gets back to the current R session. (I'd also guess there's some option to make it more verbose, but am not sure about that).